# How to configure SSO in moodle

Tags: java, single-sign-on, moodle

I am new to moodle and I want to bypass login screen of moodle and make login rest call to bypass this screen, can I do this using SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost is the default theme you'll see after Moodle installation.

1. Install a custom Single Sign On (SSO) by navigating to Site Administration -> Plugins -> Install plugins
   and drag-n-drop the downloaded zip file into the filepicker-container.
2. After that you'll get a confirmation page saying -> Current release information (Moodle 3.11 (Build: 20210517)), Server checks, Other checks (you'll see php_extensions with other compatibilities in green OK status).
   At the end of the screen you'll see **Your server environment meets all minimum requirements** and click on the continue button.

2.1. Next screen is **Plugins check**. and click **Upgrade Moodle database now** button.

2.2. **Upgrading to new version** and click continue.

3. Enable the Single Sign On (SSO) extension on Moodle by navigating to
   Site Administration -> Plugins -> Authentication -> Manage Authentication and enable  SSO plugin.

3.1. Search SSO in site administration page and you can all available and active SSO. Navigate the newly installed SSO plugin and set the credentials as directed. It'll tell you to create an account and add some secret keys or ID.

Some of the inbuilt OAuth 2 Services you can enable and use them as login like Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Nextcloud and Open Badges. Visit the link in your localhost moodle to get started.
http://localhost:80/moodle/admin/tool/oauth2/issuers.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kaych22 , I have application in java where users login to my app and should also login to moodle as well. I tried multiple plugins but none of them works fine with java, can you share link of plugin to install.

Comment: Sure. You need to download Java SSO plugin and make an account in miniOrange to access and test your app. They've free (Unlimited Authentications, configure ID, URL and set login) and premium plugin as well.  https://plugins.miniorange.com/java-single-sign-on-sso-connector.

Comment: @Yesha I would suggest you to stick with Moodle because you might have to develop separate Java plugin to show at least - users with their details, courses assigned, progress  and upcoming exams inside you Java app. You can install https://github.com/dmirandaa/moodle-auth_saml2sso zip and configure your requirements whether you want to keep app files or database, login, in same directory/server. Also, you can check official Moodle YouTube channel where they share How-To use Moodle. Future companies and universities have added Moodle as their organization's  and skills growth.